# Как подобраться к элементам SVG через JS?

Tags: javascript, svg

Всем доброго дня. 
При верстке сайта столкнулся с проблемой в работе с SVG. 
Есть SVG-шка подобной структуры:

```html
<svg id="district">
  <path id="black1"></path>
  <path id="black2"></path>
  <path id="white1"></path>
  <path id="white2"></path>
</svg>
```

Задача стоит в том чтобы при наведении на #white1 к #black1 добавлялся какой-то класс , через который я буду изменяться исходные стили этого элемента. 
Таким способом не получается:

```js
$('#white1').hover(
  function() {
    $('#black1').toggleClass('new');
  }
);
```

Я так понимаю что специфика работы с svg элементами в js совсем иная. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить данную задачу ?

Comment: Какая версия jQuery? В 2.2 и 1.12 все должно работать как надо: http://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/08/jquery-2-2-and-1-12-released/

Comment: https://jsbin.com/keyitu/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('svg path').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  },
  function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }
);
```

```css
svg path.active {
  fill: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="400">
  <path d="M 0,0 100,0 100,100, 0,100 z" fill="green"></path>
  <path d="M 100,0 200,0 200,100, 100,100 z" fill="blue"></path>
  <path d="M 0,100 100,100 100,200, 0,200 z" fill="red"></path>
</svg>
```